# Unable to use Drag and Drop Ordering Feature in Articles or Modules

Tags: joomla-3.4, article-manager, module-manager

I am using Chrome version 44.0 (most up-to-date version), and I am using Joomla 3.4.3.

I sorted by the order using the drop down menu as well as the 2-triangles icon on the left. I see the 3 dots come up dark after sorting, as it is allowing me to drag and drop, but when I click on the 3 dots and drag, I end up selecting texts. I can't even re-order the modules or articles.

Even when the list is not ordered, I get  a little pop-up message saying that I need to sort the list to reorder, and I do that, and then I still can't re-order the modules as I keep selecting texts. I tried clicking once, clicking twice, pressing up or down, but it won't drag.

Is there any other way to reorder this?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? (press F12)

Comment: There are two errors, which are: 
Uncaught ReferenceError: Class is not defined
index.php?option=com_modules:104  AND  Uncaught TypeError: Joomla.JMultiSelect is not a function

Comment: That's probably why your drag&drop doesn't work aswell... Try to search Google for answers on those errors.

Comment: I tested on the other computer and it worked. So I restart my computer, and now it magically worked. The errors disappeared and I was able to drag and drop. Thanks for your help.

Comment: So maybe it was a chrome plugin that crashed... Problem fixed :-)

Answer (score 2):

while I'm not sure why the drag-and-drop order behavior isn't working for you, for modules at least, if you open the module there is an 'Ordering' configuration option that lets you select the order it should appear in.

Maybe a dumb question, but does your cursor change to the 4-way arrows before you grab the item to drag it?

Comment: Thanks for giving me another option to re-order -- that was a bit confusing and required a little trial and error to get what I wanted, but it did what I wanted.

and also, no it does not change to 4-way arrows or any other arrows.